ffmpeg doesn't work, when starting up it doesn't play music, it gives errors
import discord
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import os
import random
from gtts import gTTS
import asyncio

TOKEN="***"
VOICE_CHANNEL_ID=11122224444

class Voice_Bot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True
        intents.voice_states=True
        super().__init__(intents=intents)
        print(os.getcwd())
        self.sounds_hello = os.listdir(os.path.join('sounds','hello'))
        self.sounds_bye = os.listdir('sounds\\bye')
        self.sounds = os.listdir('sounds\\nature')

    async def on_ready(self):        
        self.voice_channel = self.get_channel(VOICE_CHANNEL_ID) 
        if self.voice_channel == None:
            print('Не удалось подключиться к голосовому каналу.')
            return
        self.voice_client = await self.voice_channel.connect()
        print('Бот подключен к голосовому каналу')
        await self.text_to_speech("Lets play Guess the Tune")
        
    async def on_message(self,message):
        if message.author==self.user:
            return
        if message.content.startswith("game"):
            await self.text_to_speech("let's start the game guess the melody")
            music=os.listdir("sounds\\music")
            self.melody=random.choice(music)
            await self.play_sound(f"sounds\\music\\{self.melody}")
        elif message.content==self.melody[0:len(self.melody)-4]:
            if (self.voice_client.is_playing()):
                self.voice_client.stop()
            await self.text_to_speech(f"Congratulations, {message.author.name} answered correctly! To continue, type game")
        else:
            if (self.voice_client.is_playing()):
                self.voice_client.stop()
            await self.text_to_speech(f"Unfortunately, {message.author.name} did not guess. To continue, write game")


    async def on_voice_state_update(self,member,before,after):
        if member.id ==self.user.id:
            print('Someone entered or left the voice channel.')
        else:
            try:
                if before.channel == None:
                    print(f'{member.name} entered the voice channel {after.channel}.')
                    await self.play_sound(f'sounds\\hello\\{random.choice(self.sounds_hello)}')
                elif after.channel == None:
                    print(f'{member.name} left the voice channel {before.channel}.')
                    await self.play_sound(f'sounds\\bye\\{random.choice(self.sounds_bye)}')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in on_voise_state_update: {e}")

    async def text_to_speech(self,text):
        try:
            tts = gTTS(text=text, lang ="en")
            tts.save("text.mp3")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error e: {e}")
        await self.voice_channel.send(text)
        await self.play_sound("text.mp3")

    def play_sound(self,path):
        print(path)
        source=discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=path, executable="ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")
        if (self.voice_client.is_playing()):
            self.voice_client.stop()
        self.voice_client.play(source)                

client = Voice_Bot()
client.run(TOKEN)

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/ys8Xza0w.jpg)

Please don't post your tokens or any other private information on SO. Because you've posted code with the token please asap change the token and delete the one that was used in the question.
